# Mathjax Rendering in List View

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, ios-app

My problem is this: [image]
**This is visually unappealing. I'm wondering why the app doesn't render the mathjax equations, which would enhance the experience?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my surprise, the person working on the iOS app (Brian Nickel) has not ruled out this idea completely. I copy [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264612)  which applies to both comments and titles.

> I've toyed around with the idea but it's not a trivial problem.  On the web, MathJax is free to run across the entire page but in the mobile apps, each question/answer is boxed in its own web view and separate from the native title and comment elements.  Comments for example, are rendered by first using the DTHTML HTML to NSAttributedString parser and having TTTAttributedLabel draw them.  I've also not seen a way to run MathJax independent of a browser so that rules out a JavaScriptCore pipeline.
>
> The process would be look something like this:
>
> 1. Create a per-site/per-configuration offscreen UIWebView/WKWebView with MathJax configured.
> 2. When MathJax is detected in a title or comment, send it to a rendering queue.
> 3. In the queue, write the MathJax blob to a the UIWebView, trigger MathJax rendering, then pass back the SVG blob.
> 4. Use the SVG blob with an SVG to UIImage renderer.
> 5. Rewrite the attributed string to include an image attachment.
> 6. Recalculate cell height, reload the cell/table view.  Probably batch updates to not hit the UI too many times.
>
> It's definitely in the realm of possibility but not something I'll be tackling in the near future.